# How to generate a free SSL certificate for Shiny app hosted on Shiny Server?

Tags: authentication, nginx, shiny, ssl-certificate, auth0

I have created a Shiny web app which is currently being hosted on the free version of the Shiny server. I want to add simple user authentication (like Google login) which the free version of the Shiny server does not let you do.
Therefore I decided to install nginx server for reverse proxy and add Auth0 authentication (free version).

Thus as of now, the following is done :

- App running on Shiny Server (at localhost)
  The app name is **twitterAnalysis** and the address is **http://localhost:3838/twitterAnalysis**  (I am hosting it on my own computer)
- Nginx reverse proxy server is also configured and is able to serve the above app at port 82 (url : **http://localhost:82**

Now, that all the above is done, the last phase is to add authentication to the app running on the Nginx server.

### THE ISSUE

Now, to be able to add authentication (via Auth0) I first need to download SSL certificates.
However, I have not been able to download/generate the SSL certificate because the link which they ask (the link to the app) is either rejected or leads to errors.

Here is the link to the website to generate a free SSL : https://www.sslforfree.com/

The following is the URL I use to generate a free SSL certificate: http://localhost:3838/twitterAnalysis

The error I get is *INVALID DOMAINS*

Thus, to summarize :

1. What is the issue? Why is the domain name getting rejected?
2. How do I get a free SSL certificate that lets me get all the job done?

**NOTE**

- [This](https://auth0.com/blog/adding-authentication-to-shiny-server/) is the tutorial I am using to get all the above done. It's very good, but not exhaustive.
- I want to host the app on my computer and get all the job done exactly as explained in the article (then I can port the whole app-server configuration later to a Raspberry Pi which I can use as my permanent web server).
- I am completely new to all this web server configuration, so a little bit of ELI5 would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

SSL certificate is given for one (or sometimes several) internet domains. You should have a domain name registered referring to external IP of you server.  localhost is not a valid domain name for this purpose. sslforfree.com than check before issuing certificate that domain is really yours by checking record in domain DNS zone or by checking the file on the host in domain via http or ftp.